# parsing XML, report unknown tags/attributes

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I need to parse a well-defined XML file.
I defined structures and used

`err = xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &mystruct)`

It works well. But I need to detect unknown tags and attributes.

When I see an unknown tag I want to report the full tag "as-is" back to the user. The same for unknown attribute.

How I can do that in Go?

Comment: The std lib's `encoding/xml` package has no support for what you're after. You'll need to look for 3rd party packages or implement this yourself. The most you can do with the standard library is to collect unknown elements/attributes using the `,any` tag option, however then, you would have to pollute all of your structs where the unknowns can occur. E.g. https://play.golang.com/p/RdB9Ub8fv__Q

Comment: It looks like I need something custom.
Your solution won't work if I add an attribute:
var data = []byte(`<body attr="foo" uattr="bar" uattr2="baz">
 <elem>abc</elem>
 <uelem uuattr="qwe">def</uelem>
 <uelem2>ghi</uelem2>
 <elem2 subattr="quux" usubattr="...">
  <subelem>jkl</subelem>
  <usubelem>mno</usubelem>
 </elem2>

For the unknown elements I just need to report them in full. No processing is required.
For the unknown attributes within known elements I need to report them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) to parse XML file and extract data and without defined XML data structure, it's a XPath query package.

```golang
f, err := os.Open("../books.xml")
doc, err := xmlquery.Parse(f)
list:=xmlquery.Find(doc, "//book//author")
```